# Log handling in python - sending logs to kafka

Tags: python, logging, apache-kafka

I'm trying to make use of [kafka-logging-handler](https://github.com/redhat-aqe/kafka-logging-handler) to configure logging to send to a kafka server.

I'm using a yaml file to configure logging (via `logging.config.dictConfig`)

When I try to use it, I just get an error `Unable to add handler 'kafka_log_handler'` but can't get any more detail on what's going wrong.

It appears that error happens in `logging.config.add_handlers`

Grateful for any help with getting this working.

This is how I'm loading the config and testing it.

---

### EDIT - adding detail to allow minimal reproducible example

Note that `producer.send` works fine and is received by Kafka, but nothing from the logger.

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
import yaml
import logging.config
import os
from kafka import KafkaProducer


filepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
with open("{}/logconfig.yml".format(filepath), "r") as f:
    config_dict = yaml.safe_load(f)

logging.config.dictConfig(config_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.info("test")

    msg = str.encode("test message")
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=os.environ.get("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS"))
    producer.send(os.environ.get("TOPIC_NAME"), msg)
    producer.flush()
```

This results in

```sh
Unable to add handler 'kafka_log_handler'
```

and `receiver.py` (see below for code) gets:

```sh
received b'test message' on: logtopic
```

and this is the config...

`logconfig.yml`

```yaml
version: 1
formatters:
  default: {'format': '%(threadName)s:[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s'}
  json: {'class': pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter, 'format': '%(threadName)s:[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s' }
handlers:
  console_handler:
    level: INFO
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    formatter: json
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  kakfa_log_hander:
    level: INFO
    class: kafka_logger.handlers.KafkaLoggingHandler
    hosts_list: MY_IP_ADDRESS:9091
    topic: logtopic
    security_protocol: "PLAINTEXT"
    kafka_producer_args:
      api_version_auto_timeout_ms: 1000000
      request_timeout_ms: 1000000
    additional_fields:
      service: test-service
    formatter: json
loggers:
  default_logger:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console_handler]
  debug_logger:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console_handler]
  kfa_logger:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console_handler, kafka_log_handler]
disable_existing_loggers: False
```

To run a quick kafka server for testing, use this `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_PORT: 2181
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zookeeper:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - ./data/zookeeper/data:/data
      - ./data/zookeeper/datalog:/datalog
  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.0
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9091:9091"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19091,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9091
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19091,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${IP_ADDRESS}:9091
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - ./data/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

`receiver.py`

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import os

consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=os.environ.get("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS"))
consumer.subscribe(os.environ.get("TOPIC_NAME"))

for message in consumer:
    print("received {} on: {}".format(message.value, message.topic))
```

`.env`

```
TOPIC_NAME=logtopic
BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=MY_IP_ADDRESS:9091
IP_ADDRESS=MY_IP_ADDRESS
```

EDIT2:

The error seems to be how I'm using `DictConfig`, as the following works:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

import logging
from kafka_logger.handlers import KafkaLoggingHandler

import os

KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER = os.environ.get("BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS")
TOPIC = os.environ.get("TOPIC_NAME")

logger = logging.getLogger("MyCoolProject")

# Instantiate your kafka logging handler object
kafka_handler_obj = KafkaLoggingHandler(
    KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER, TOPIC, security_protocol="PLAINTEXT"
)

logger.addHandler(kafka_handler_obj)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.info("Happy Logging!")
```

Comment: Did you make Kafka run on port 9094 instead of 9092? IMO, I'd suggest using Filebeat/Fluentd/rsyslog to be programming language agnostic for how data arrives to Kafka. Log to (rotating) files; have another process read that.

Comment: Yes, running it on 9094. Was hoping to get this to work, but will look into fluentd

Comment: How did you start Kafka? Directly with `kafka-server-start` or Docker or something else?

Comment: It's running in kubernetes. Installed using helm - https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/kafka?modal=security-report

Comment: In that case, advertisedListeners defaults to an empty array and your brokers aren't accessible outside of the cluster. Secondly, if your Python code also runs in pods of kubernetes, localhost obviously is not a Kafka broker, and you should instead be using the Kafka Service name within the namespace

Comment: I have this set `KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9093,CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9094` and am using the actual IP address of the kafka service rather than localhost. It's definitely available from outside cluster as `KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers).send(topic_name, msg)` works from outside. The problem is just with sending using `kafka_logger.handlers.KafkaLoggingHandler`

Comment: That's not the advertised listeners... Do you also have a NodePort and ExternalService for that? You should point at an Ingress, not a Kafka pod who's IP can change... Based on what you've posted in the question, how would we have known if you weren't using localhost? You should edit your post to include a [mcve] of your complete cluster setup. Otherwise, test your shown code here with a Kafka broker running on the address you've shown

Comment: Added detail to the question to allow testing. Have remove k8s from the equation as it's irrelevant. The broker is able to receive messages, but not from the logger.

Comment: Thanks. Does it work if you follow any of the examples in the repo or don't use DictConfig?

Comment: Yes, it works if I don't use DictConfig. I've added a working method in my question

Comment: So, if it works without it, then my suggestion would be to remove the Kafka details from the YAML file... Then, I assume you should be able to load both the YAML via `dictConfig`, then later add additional handlers manually. One benefit of that is that you can use environment variables easier for the bootstrap address

Comment: That works as a workaround, thanks.